# How to loop an image on javascript from a link?

Tags: javascript, html, image, loops

I would like to know how to loop sets of images from links provided by the user. I already have some codes that when a user insert an Url in the picture1, picture2 or picture3 box, it will randomly display those pictures all over the page and go all the way down forever. I want the "try it" button to refresh the image at the same exact location on the page after some delay. I would also like to add an other box for the user to add captions for each image they enter.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

        var y = document.getElementById("yourText").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;

        var z = document.getElementById("hisText").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;

        var total_images = 3;
        var random_number = Math.floor((Math.random()*total_images));
        var random_img = new Array();
        random_img[0] = document.createElement("IMG");
        random_img[0].setAttribute("src", x);
        random_img[0].setAttribute("width", "304");
        random_img[0].setAttribute("width", "228");
        random_img[0].setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock ");

        random_img[1] = document.createElement("IMG");
        random_img[1].setAttribute("src", y);
        random_img[1].setAttribute("width", "304");
        random_img[1].setAttribute("width", "228");
        random_img[1].setAttribute("alt", "The Solid Rock ");

        random_img[2] = document.createElement("IMG");
        random_img[2].setAttribute("src", z);
        random_img[2].setAttribute("width", "304");
        random_img[2].setAttribute("width", "228");
        random_img[2].setAttribute("alt", "The Heavy Rock ");

        document.body.appendChild(random_img[random_number]);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="myText" value="Picture1 link...">
    <input type="text" id="yourText" value="Picture2 link...">
    <input type="text" id="hisText" value="Picture 3 link...">

    <p>Click the "Try it" button to get the text in the text field.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like the image to loop and I would also like the user to be able to change the Url live.

Comment: why make things so difficult for the user? there's no browse facility even, let alone a prompt. Why not make the input type=file? then they can select images easily

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html